# How to wrap a foreach loop item in a link?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I think this question is php rather than WordPress...

I have a block of code that outputs pages which use a specific WordPress page template:

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-product.php'
));
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $page->post_title.'<br />';
}
```

My question is how do I wrap the post_title in a link (the_permalink() to the page itself)?

Comment: `echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . {$page->post_title} . '</a'>;`?

Comment: This wouldn't work. get_the_permalink has to be used inside a loop. get_pages will return an array of post objects. You have to use get_permalink and pass in the post object.

Comment: I have used get_page_link in my answer. Wordpress referenced to way of achieving the users question in the actual wordpress documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You would do the following:

```
foreach ( $pages as $page ){
    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a><br />', get_permalink( $page ), $page->post_title );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
get_page_link( $page->ID )
```

In your code..

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
  'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
  'meta_value' => 'page-product.php'
));
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo '<a href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">' . $page->post_title.'</a><br         />';
}
```

For more information Wordpress always has lots of example and information on what your using.
In this case I used actual code provided by Wordpress themselves, thus will be best way to do this. Please see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-product.php'
));
foreach($pages as $page){

///Do not forget to escape the title
    echo '<a href="' . get_page_link($page->ID)  . '">' . esc_html($page->post_title) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment above detailing why get_the_permalink won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. bodi0 - I liked the esc_html, thanks. I finally figured it out slightly differently with this:

```
<?php
 $studentpages = get_pages(array(
 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
 'meta_value' => 'students.php'
 ));
 foreach($studentpages as $studentpage){
 $studentlinks = get_page_link($studentpage->ID);
 echo '<a href=" '.$studentlinks.' ">'.$studentpage->post_title.'</a>' . '<br />';
 }
?>
```